# compile error in vs code when using python decorator

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-decorators

```
import yaml, os
import logging.config

def setup_logging(default_path='logging.yaml', default_level=logging.INFO, env_key='LOG_CFG'):
    """load logging.yaml file or use system environment variable 'LOG_CFG' to setup logging configuration"""
    path = default_path
    value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
    if value:
        path = value
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
        
def logger_decorate(cls: type):
    """logger decorator for each class"""

    # setup logging
    setup_logging()

    aname = '_{}__log'.format(cls.__name__)
    setattr(cls, aname, logging.getLogger(cls.__module__ + '.' + cls.__name__))
    return cls


@logger_decorate
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    
    def sayHello(self):
        self.__log.info('sayHello called')
        print("hello", self.name)
    
    def test(self):
        self.__log.info('test called')
        getattr(self, 'sayHello')()
        
test = Test("john")
test.test()
```

will print

> 2018-09-28 00:30:51,881 - **main**.Test - INFO - test called
>
> 2018-09-28 00:30:51,882 - **main**.Test - INFO - sayHello called
>
> hello john

but there will be compile error in the vscode, anyone knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: was this ever fixed? I am having this issue currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I could figure out a workaround to solve the compile error in the VSCode Editor with adding an attribute with name **__log** in the class

```
@logger_decorate
class Test(object):
    __log = None # workaround

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def sayHello(self):
        self.__log.info('sayHello called')
        print("hello", self.name)

    def test(self):
        self.__log.info('test called')
        getattr(self, 'sayHello')()

test = Test("john")
test.test()
```